# How do I set networking enabled by default?

Tags: configuration, network-manager

When I log into my computer, networking is disabled.  I always have to enable it so I can connect to the internet.  Does anyone know how to set it to enabled by default?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the *network-manager* applet menu (right click), select *edit connections*. Edit the connection you wish to automatically connect and select the *connect automatically* checkbox.

If you wish to start a connection before you log in, select the *available to all users* checkbox. This is most useful with wireless connections which usually are available only after login.

Comment: Today it worked fine.  Looking at the connections, for some reason I have 2 ethernet connections. The one that it was using yesterday didn't have `available to all users` checked, so it makes sense why it wasn't enabled at log in.  The one it used today did, so it was enabled when I logged in.  I'm just going to delete the one I used yesterday, because it is redundant.  Thanks for the help.