# Network Preferences Occasionally Defaulted upon Login

Tags: networking, default

Sometimes (but not all the time, oddly enough), when I log into my system, Networking will be disabled by default. Is this a common issue, or is there some workaround I missed to set 'On' as the PERMANENT default (!?).

Comment: When you say disabled do you mean not connected or something more than that?

Comment: I mean actually disabled. Like, I have to right-click on the nm-applet and click "enable networking."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/765/how-do-i-set-networking-enabled-by-default) looks very similar. [Ressu](https://askubuntu.com/users/42/ressu)'s accepted answer runs something like this:

Right-click the Network Manager applet and choose `Edit Connections`. Edit the connection you want to be used on login and check the "Connect automatically" and "Available to all users" checkboxes.